# "onclick" event not firing when only one row in my select

Tags: javascript

I have a simple select object:

```
<select id="location" name="location" size="1"> 
    <option onclick="showLocationDetails(this)" value="25">Mars</option>   
    <option onclick="showLocationDetails(this)" value="26">Venus</option>
</select>
```

When I select one of the values, it runs my "showLocationDetails" javascript just fine:

```
function showLocationDetails(selected_option) {

    console.log("inside showLocationDetails");
    // Do a bunch of other stuff
}
```

The problem is that if I only have one option in my select, like so:

```
<select id="location" name="location" size="1"> 
    <option onclick="showLocationDetails(this)" value="25">Mars</option>   
</select>
```

Then showLocationDetails() is never triggered.

I tried using the onchange event, but same result.

Using Google Chrome if that matters.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: not all browsers support onclick on an option. onchange on the select is a better choice.

Comment: Well, since there is only one, nothing can change, not even at _onchange_

Comment: Please look at the updated answer

Comment: Should this fire on user selection or on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Onclick` is not a global event listener for `<option>`. Some of the browsers, might support it. But, you need a standard solution.

Put your event listener on the `<select>` tag.

Look at this example and create your own:

```js
function myFunc(msg) {
  if(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
}

//Perform the first time:
first_value = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
myFunc(first_value);
```

```html
<select onchange="myFunc(this.value)" id="mySelect">
<option value="hello">Hi</option>
<option value="see you">Bye</option>
</select>
```

**By the way,** if it's possible to use jQuery, you can implement it easier. Also, putting the event listener inside the elements properties is not recommended

Comment: The problem as when there is only 1 item, not 2 ... which this will not solve

Comment: @LGSon, The first call would be performed and grabs the location details. After that, there is no need to change

Comment: Excellent!  That did the trick.  I put removed onclick and put the "onchange" on the select instead of the options, and it worked.

Comment: @B.Krafft. Glad to help. You can check my answer as the correct answer. So, no more developer spends time on this topic

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can bind the event listener to the select element as opposed to the option elements, as some browser won't support that.

Your main problem is that no action will be triggered on selection since you only have one option.

Taking this into account, you can have a function that is called with the onPageLoad event that would trigger your showLocationDetails function for your select based on the selected option. If you're dynamically populating the options through js, you can call this function everytime you are done populating the options.

Like this:

```
function example()
{
    showLocationDetails($('#location').val());
}


$(document).ready(example);
```

Comment: (S)he is looking for a native JavaScript solution. Not jQuery.

Comment: I used jquery as an example to get my point across. Everything else I said is still valid with a pure javascript implementation and will address the stated problem. @Mojtaba, I don't believe that warrants a downvote.

Comment: I just put a comment